# Find the maximum value of $2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the maximum value of $2x + 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1.$

I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use RMS-AM, but I'm not sure which values to substitute for $a$ and $b$ in the inequality.

Comment: WLOG $$x=\cos^2t$$

Comment: add -1 and use AM-QM

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+\sqrt{x(1-x)}=y$

$\implies x-x^2=(y-x)^2\iff2x^2-x(2y+1)+y^2=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant $$(2y+1)^2-8y^2\ge0$$

As $y\ge0,2y+1\ge2\sqrt2y\iff2(\sqrt2-1)y\le1\iff y\le\dfrac{\sqrt2+1}2$